# Rooks in three dimensions

Tags: co.combinatorics, chess

Given is an infinite 3-dim chess board and a black king. What is the minimum number of white rooks necessary that can guarantee a checkmate in a finite number of moves?

(In 3-dimensional chess rooks move in straight lines, entering each cube through a face and departing through the opposite face.  Kings can move to any cube which shares a face, edge, or corner with the cube that the king starts in.
See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_chess)).

**Update:** Comments (below the line) give interesting information on this problem including a connection to Conway's angel problem with 2-angel (Zare) and interesting comments towards positive answer and connection with "kinggo" (Elkies). Also a link to an identical SE question is provided [MSE Question 155777](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155777/guaranteed-checkmate-with-rooks-in-high-dimensional-chess) (Snyder).

Comment: Can a $d$-dimensional rook move to any point on any coordinate-axis-parallel line, or to any point on any coordinate-plane-parallel hyperplane? Either way, nice question!


Comment: Not sure the answer is finite, as the number of rooks to create various kinds of restrictive cages is far larger than the number of moves necessary for a king to escape a half-finished cage. What experiments have you done so far?

Comment: A nice question, but one already asked on rec. puzzles in 1994. Voting to close.

Comment: Hu? Why was this closed, what is the answer?

Comment: I guess it was closed because people think that it's not really a math question... But there certainly a number of people who seem to have appreciated the question.

Comment: It's closed because there seem to be too many trigger-happy people on the local `closing committee'. This is a bit worrying. 

Comment: @Nikita, I voted to close because I saw no effort on the part of the OP. This item is ripe for computer modelling, and I do not volunteer to do that. If ivan wants to give some motivation, and some sense that he knows why the answer is finite, that might matter. Note that it has been four hours with no follow-up from the OP.

Comment: @Nikita: the question is not at all new, the OP gave no background, the question is a cute puzzle which has no apparently connection to any research (there might in fact be some, but the OP did not provide any), as @Will has correctly pointed out, the OP gave no indication that he had made any attempt to make progress on the question himself. Need I go on? The "committee", as you call it, in aggregate, has expended a vast amount of time and effort contributing to MO (around 55K rep points between us), so clearly cares about keeping it a good place. Have some respect.

Comment: @Igor, I prefer MOfia to committee. Also, I think the OP misses this point in the FAQ: "MathOverflow is not a discussion forum. As a side-effect of being very good for to-the-point questions and answers, the Stack Exchange software is bad for discussions and designed to minimize them" with the profile quote: "I am not a mathematician even though I've had some university level training. I am here mostly to read and to provoke a few discussions."  


Comment: META: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1384/rooksinthreedimensions/  

Comment: As a question, it is quite intriguing.  As material appropriate for MathOverflow, it is not.  There is a way to turn this into something appropriate for this forum, but I doubt that the original poster is motivated to do so.  Gerhard "Voting To Support Closing Votes" Paseman, 2012.06.08

Comment: Igor, are you saying that whether this can be done with finitely many rooks has a well-known answer or that it's well-known to be open?

Comment: As we all can see, there are members who have doubts whether the question should be closed. Which by definition means that it shouldn't. 

Comment: If the devil could win against a $2$-angel in Conway's angel problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_problem then the rooks could win in some finite number of moves. However, a $2$-angel can win. 

Comment: No Nikita, that is not the definition for criteria against closing the question, nor should doubting members be a significant criterion.  Follow the meta link above and participate if you want to see your ideas enforced.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.06.08

Comment: @noah, it is well known to be well known in those circles who care about such things.

Comment: Then why not just answer the question?

Comment: Voting to close because it's a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155777/.  I still think that if the answer is well-known then someone should answer it or link to an answer.

Comment: In three dimensions a finite number of rooks should suffice by projection to
"Kinggo": the King starts in the middle of an $N \times N$ square, then after
each King move the opponent gets to claim a square at the edge of the board;
the King is known to lose by force ($N=33$ suffices for Kinggo, maybe here
we'll use something like $N=45$ to accommodate the initial setup).  The king
is then restricted to an $N \times N \times \infty$ box, so $N^2$ rooks
suffice to force checkmate, and actually $5N$ will do.  So $200$ rooks
win in ${\bf Z}^3$.  In ${\bf Z}^4$ and above, I don't know.


Comment: Will Jagy, are you able to direct me to the part of the FAQ that stipulates that it is considered undesirable to post a MathOverflow question before leaving work, and then come back the next morning to deal with replies? I ask because some might be unaware with this rule, and, finding that it is in concord with their personal schedules, feel a certain compulsion to do so.

Comment: There's actually a two-parameter family of questions: we can vary
not just the dimension of the board but also the number of coordintates
that a Rook is allowed to change per move.  So standard chess (where
three Rooks suffice) is $(2,1)$, and the present question is $(3,1)$.


Comment: Correction: The "initial setup" actually takes a move per Rook, which
might seem to give rise to Kinggo with the King moving twice for each square the Go side claims -- which is exactly the "2-angel" in
D.Zare's answer.  However, we can set up the rooks in the correct plane
before deciding where each Rook goes, and that might be close enough to
a "1-angel" that the Rooks still win.  Hm...


Comment: What an interesting discussion in the comments of a closed question!  If only this were an isolated incident...

Comment: @James Cranch, please see http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1384/rooksinthreedimensions  and, if you are so moved, (there is a separate registration for Meta) post further comments there. 

Comment: @Steve D: if your point is that questions should be closed less frequently, the point is to prevent a deluge of sewage from drowning this (so far quite successful) group. With this question, there are excellent reasons to close (see my comments), and it is quite possible that if, say, @Noam wanted to post a version of this question, none of the reasons I give would apply, and the question would stay open. For that matter, if you really care, you could do some thinking and ask a version yourself, likely with the same result. This sort of thing has been done many times. By all means, go ahead.

Comment: Note the question is still open at math.SE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155777/

Comment: @Igor: I think the question should be closed, because it is a duplicate of one on math.SE, and we don't do too much closing over there. However, if I were ivan, I'd probably never ask a question here again: his first post here, and instead of people with high rep (the "committee" I should respect) encouraging him to alter the question and phrase it differently, show what he knows, etc., he has people jumping at the chance to close his question, and later refer to it as "sewage".  Why in the world would he (or any other new user treated so) stick around?

Comment: And to be clear, I don't think "asked on rec.puzzles in 1994" is a good enough reason to close a question.  If you provided a link, maybe; but just a statement like that and then voting to close is not really becoming of a high-rep user such as yourself. And I don't think the policy here should be to close these questions, then have a high-rep user repost it with more details.  Shouldn't we *encourage* the OP to alter the question instead?

Comment: @Steve D, I  encourage you also to post on Meta at http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1384/rooksinthreedimensions which is where we try to move the discussions that are about MO policy rather than mathematics. I cannot promise Igor will answer you there, but if what you really need is a personal response from him you may always email him. The same applies to me. That is my preference, and I actually answer my email, but the middle ground is Meta.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that the dynamical system is converging to a stable attractor in which all questions here are closed and all questions at math.SE stay open.

Comment: @Gil: thanks for the helpful update, so people wouldn't miss the mathematics in all the excitement!  

Comment: After reading this long discussion, I'm still still not sure what is known about this problem. I can see how you can enforce checkmate with 65 rooks, which I doubt is close to optimal. Is it generally known that it can be done with fewer? I'm not sure if it's worth posting my solution (I'd probably post it on math.SE anyway).

Comment: @george this seems to have been open until now, so posting it would be a fine thing.

Comment: @greg: I don't know about math.se, but to first order, that seems like a fine steady state (most questions are bad, a negligible number are good, but negligible is a relative term...)

Comment: @steve d: I did not say this question was sewage, merely that it there is a lot of sewage, and we must be vigilant. I don't think our job is to be mollycoddlers. If this encourages Ivan to think and do a little more work before asking, great!

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answers. I do not check Internet during weekends so was late in posting. In fact, I have come up with a horribly complicated strategy where approx. 500 rooks will suffice but Noam seems to hint at a much simpler one, if I can understand how it works (which I can't).

Of course, it is not a research question, just something which came up by idle musings.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as I know, it is still open whether or not there is any finite number of rooks which can force checkmate. However, this is possible. I answered the question over at [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/156693/1321) describing a strategy which forces checkmate with 96 rooks. This is certainly not optimal. The strategy I describe is very wasteful, keeping some rooks in place even when they are not actually needed, so it can be improved at the expense of becoming more difficult to describe.

Comment: @George Lowther: Looked at your nice answer on math.stackexchange. Shouldn't it generalize to $n$ dimensions? As per your answer, the rooks should be placed far away from the king along the $n$-th coordinate. As per your answer, the initial steps would still allow the king to roam freely along the $n$-th coordinate but aim to restrict its movement projected to the first $n-1$ coordinates. Each rook, far away along the $n$-th coordinate, guards one square having the same $n$-th coordinate as the king.

Comment: As in your answer, at the penultimate step, the king should be trapped in the middle of a $3^{n-1}$ cube, but be able to move freely along the $n$-th coordinate. (Each position on the boundary of this cube being guarded by a rook far away along the $n$-th coordinate.)Then place a rook far away along the $n$-th coordinate but having the same first $n-1$ coordinates as the king, to give checkmate. The initial number of rooks to begin with probably depends on $n$, no idea how exactly though.


Comment: I am confused. In the first sentence, you say it's still open whether or not any finite number of rooks can force checkmate. In the second sentence, you say that 96 rooks can force checkmate. I suspect that it's the first sentence which I am parsing incorrectly, but in that case I have no idea what it is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 7):

The following is for a finite board (the question actually assumes an infinite board).

For an $N\times N \times N$ board, wouldn't $2N$ rooks suffice? The idea comes from adapting the checkmate with two rooks for the two dimensional case in which the two rooks alternate rows and force the king to the last rank.

For the three dimensional case, for each $y$ with $1\leq y \leq N$, place one rook at $(1,y,k)$ and another at $(2,y,k+1)$. Then, for $y$ going from $1$ to $N$, move the rook at $(1,y,k)$ to the square $(1,y,k+2)$. Again, for $y$ going from $1$ to $N$, move the rook at $(2,y,k+1)$ to $(2,y,k+3)$. Each for loop over $y$ involves moving, alternately, the rooks with $x$ coordinate $1$ by increasing their $z$ coordinate by $2$ units, or the rooks with $x$ coordinate $2$ by increasing their $z$ coordinate by $2$ units. We alternate, so that a for loop in which the rooks with $x$ coordinate $1$ are moved is followed by a for loop in which the rooks with $x$ coordinate $2$ are moved, and vice versa. Eventually, either the rooks with $x$ coordinate $1$ or the rooks with $x$ coordinate $2$ will have $z$ coordinate $N$.

The effect of this is that a subset of the squares guarded by the rooks form a "floor" of two layers that keeps moving upward. So if the black king is between this "floor" and the top of the $N\times N\times N$ cube, it gets pushed to the top face. The "floor" must be moved upward in such a way that it never becomes disconnected, so that the black king can never escape to beneath the "floor" through some gap.

For an infinite board, @Noam Elkies has already mentioned $5N$, so the following is not an improvement: the "ceiling" (and the other walls of the $N\times N \times N$ cube) can be formed by placing $N$ more rooks at $(N,y,N)$, for each $y$ with $1\leq y\leq N$, and $N-1$ more rooks at $(x,1,N)$, for each $x$ with $1 \leq x \leq N-1$, and $N-1$ more rooks at $(x,N,N)$ for each $x$ with $1 \leq x \leq N-1$.

Comment: Actually, as long as $N$ is large enough to get started, 12 rooks should suffice. Use 4 rooks to perform the "blocking move" described in my math.SE post, with another 4 rooks protecting them. This traps the king in one half of the board - i.e. to one side of a plane containing these 8 rooks. Then, move the other 4 rooks in to push the king one step away from this plane, and move 4 of the original 8 rooks across to protect them. Repeat until the king gets pushed off the edge of the board.

Comment: The question is for an infinite board though, so there is no "last rank".

Comment: @George Lowther: Right! An infinite board. Corrected the answer, thank you very much!